# Constructing a list of objects within the object itself without creating a new object

Tags: c#

In basics my code:

```
public class Player
    {
        public ConsoleColor color;
        public ConsoleKey upKey, downKey, leftKey, rightKey;
    public static Player[] players;

    public void addPlayer(ConsoleColor _color, ConsoleKey _upKey, ConsoleKey _downKey, ConsoleKey _leftKey, ConsoleKey _rightKey)
    {
        Player.players[Player.players.Length] = new Player(_color, _upKey, _downKey, _leftKey, _rightKey);
    }

    public Player()
    {

    }
    public void attack()
    {

    }

    public Player(ConsoleColor _color, ConsoleKey _upKey, ConsoleKey _downKey, ConsoleKey _leftKey, ConsoleKey _rightKey)
    {
        color = _color;
        upKey = _upKey;
        downKey = _downKey;
        leftKey = _leftKey;
        rightKey = _rightKey;
    }
}

void mainLoop()
{
    Player.addPlayer(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleKey.W, ConsoleKey.S, ConsoleKey.A, ConsoleKey.D);
    Player.addPlayer(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleKey.UpArrow, ConsoleKey.DownArrow, ConsoleKey.LeftArrow, ConsoleKey.RightArrow);
    for (int _player = 0; _player < Player.players.Length; _player++)
    {
        Player.players[_player].attack();
    }
}
```

The purpose of doing this is so that the code will be reusable. In the end this will be a basicmultiplayer game.

What i am currently doing is creating the class "Player" that also contains a list of all instances (objects) of itself. This i need to do for numerous reasons, but the most important one is to make the code as reusable and intergratable as possible.

When i try to do thi, my problem is at "Player.addPlayer()". It will not accept this without me making a Player object. I would prefer not doing this.

Comment: You're mixing business logic with presentation logic. Your player should be a model that is rendered by another part of your app.

Comment: `Player` class contains a collection of `Player` classes.  I get what you're going for but I would consider making your code more intuitive

Answer (score 1):

That is because `addPlayer` should be static too:

```
public static void addPlayer
```

There is a bigger problem though: your design. Instead of stuffing it all in the `Player` class: create a new class, `Players`, create non-static members like `addPlayer` there and pass around the instance of `Players`.

That is a much better and workable design than your current approach. Why? What if you want to split players in two sides? You can't group them since they are in the same static list. What if you want to remove one, etc.

And instead of an array, use a `List<Player>`, which allows automatic sizing, deletion, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. That did the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want use any method without creating an instance of class you should make it `static` like you didi with `players` property. But you should know that **actually an instance of your class creating anyway if you have static method or property in it** at application start.

So if you want to use method addPlayer like this:

```
Player.addPlayer()
```

You should declare it like this:

```
public static void addPlayer(/*...*/)
```